# How do I make my a77 go back to a single shutter click when I press the shutter release?

Tags: shutter

Sony a77 camera. Has started clicking several times when I push shutter button and then display says "processing" for a few seconds. I would like for it to go back to a single shutter click and ready to take another pic. Can't seem to find answer in manual.

Comment: feel free to return and let us know if that is resolved

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like camera is in "HDR" mode, taking several images and then combining into one, or in bracketing mode, taking several pictures with different exposure.

You can turn off HDR (manual pages 158) and bracketing in the menus (manual page 155)

You can also reset setting to factory default by doing (manual page 186)

[image: how to reset]